# How do I format an Integer using current locale in Delphi

Tags: delphi, text-formatting

```
var i : integer;

i := 1234567;
```

Given the above, I want the string "1,234,567" as output (assuming UK locale). IntToStr just gives me "1234567". I'm sure there's a one-liner for this, but I can't find it...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try the format function.

```
Label1.Caption := Format('%.0n', [i + 0.0]);
```

Answer (score 11):

Or if you need to be threadsafe or want to ensure you use the system default locale or want to specify one:

```
function FormatIntFromLCID(const AValue: Integer; const LCID: Integer = LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT): string;
var
  AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
begin
  GetLocaleFormatSettings(LCID, AFormatSettings);
  Result := FormatFloat('#,##0',AValue, AFormatSettings);
end;
```

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86002/in-delphi-how-can-you-have-currency-data-types-shown-in-different-currencies-in#87306) for a more complete discussion about formatting/locales

Answer (score 6):

s := FormatFloat('#,##0', i);

Answer (score 0):

I have this function to do it, where d means perhaps decimal number:

```
function dn(i: integer): string; 
begin 
  result := format('%.0n', [i.ToDouble]) 
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
stringreplace(format('%n',[1234567.0]),'.00','',[]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Format('%n', [12345.678]);